# How to set bold to a label without disturbing the font size and family names?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uifont

I want to set the selected label to appear bold without implementing the font family-bold version.
Ex:-
the default way to set bold is as follows

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" 
                                 size:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
```

But i want to change the font weight(i.e BOld, Italic or Underline) only. without calling the "fontWithName".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck. For non-system fonts, you have to use `fontWithName` to get to the bold version. From the documentation of `UIFont`:

> *fontName*
>   The fully specified name of the font. This name incorporates both the font family name and the specific style information for the font.

**Possible workaround:**
So, while you cannot have a generic method that would switch every font to *bold*, you could still implement this by maintaining a set of string constants that you can look up to switch to the correct bold version of the fonts you are using in your app.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a blog post about that topic.
You can see it at http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/26/uifont-from-a-css-definition/

With the code I provide there, you can get your desired UIFont as easy as:

`UIFont *myFont = [FontResolver fontWithDescription:@"font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;"];`

Answer (score 0):

```
labelName.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
```

Use this statement it will help you

Comment: But will it be useful when I am not using system font?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the system font (Helvetica Neue), you can use `boldSystemFontOfSize:`. Otherwise you're stuck specifying bold in the font name. See the [UIFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference for details.